# Django rest framework, m2m relationships and pouchdb integration

Tags: synchronization, couchdb, django-rest-framework, offlineapps

What is the best way to integrate [pouchdb](http://pouchdb.com/) in a web app with a sync feature when the backend is a [Django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) (DRF) application with a lot of many to many relationships?

For example, suppose I have models like this:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Expense(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)

# Multiple users are in the account:
class AccountUser(models.Model): 
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

With adequate serializers that also compute account total and adequate permissions.

I either need DRF to behave like [Couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/) (with rev number) or to integrate Couchdb with DRF (using Coudhdbkit? or separately?). How can I do this? Is there any other way?

Thanks

Comment: Right view without seeing a serializer and a clearer question (what is going wrong/what needs to be fixed) it's difficult to give an answer to your questions.

Comment: I have a working DRF Rest API, the question is how to integrate punchdb on the client side to work with my API? (or a rest client with a offline database and sync mechanism). Do I need to start from scratch with CouchDB? But then, how to handle complex m2m relationships like above? Or can I reproduce Couchdb sync model with DRF? Is the question more clear like that? I can paste serializers if needed... thanks

Comment: I'd reword the question as you can see it's confused people.

Comment: How to keep a couchdb synced with django rest framework. One way I guess would be to use rest hooks to post updates to couchdb when they happen.